# Detecting extrema under uncertainty?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, outliers, computational-statistics, uncertainty, extreme-value

An old version of this question was poorly articulated. Here is another go:

I have fifty objects. With a different, independent, unbiased scale for each object, I measure their weights 100 times each (5000 measurements in total). I can compute the variance $\sigma^2_i$ of each of the fifty scales based on the distribution of the measurements for each object.

Given my measurements and my $\sigma^2_i$, what is the probability for each of the objects being, in fact, the heaviest? (The prior probability is a uniform assumption - each has a $\frac{1}{50}$ chance of being the highest.)

Thank you for your help!

Example: what is the probability that term 26 is the heaviest?

[image: Example Box plot: what is the probability that object 26 is the heaviest?]

Comment: Puzzled: (1) In your attached graph it seems #26 stands out as high, not #23. (2) Can't immediately see the relevance of the link. which has many topics. (3) Not sure I understand what you mean by a group being an outlier; what is your criterion for that?

Comment: @BruceET Thank you very much for your reply - I fixed the link and the highest element I refer to. My criterion for outlier here is really finding the probability, for each term, of being the highest out of all the terms. So not necessarily an outlier per se. There could be multiple terms that are vying for being the upper extrema, and they would split the probability between them.

Comment: Well, if you have 50 groups, then doesn't each have probability $1/50$ of being the 'highest' . Still not sure what your definition of 'highest' is: has the highest mean? has the one highest single observation of all? // What kind of data do you have that shows so many outliers on the low side of the median?

Comment: @BruceET I'm interested in the statistical probability, given the distribution of measurements of each of the groups, for each group to be the highest. Highest referring to the mean, yes. Normally, one could just rank the means, but I have variances, so I'd like to use them to obtain probabilities.

Comment: You can't get probabilities out without putting some in to begin with: until you provide  (a) some *prior* probabilities for each group to be the highest and (b) a probabilistic mechanism to explain variation within each group, your question will be unanswerable.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. The prior probability is a uniform assumption - each has a 1/50 chance of being the highest. I'm not sure what you mean by providing a probabilistic mechanism; could you please clarify?

Comment: The word "expectation" makes sense only with respect to a probability distribution: what are you assuming about the distribution that implicitly governs the data in the fifty groups?

Comment: You need some kind of assumption about the distribution within each class. For example, maybe classes 1 - 49 have expected value near 1, but class 50 is generated by some process where one sample in every 100 takes value 100 trillion. You need to be able to say something about the prior probability of this happening.

Comment: Until that crucial point about "The prior probability is a uniform assumption - each has a 1/50 chance of being the highest" is explicitly stated in the post, I suspect people might keep voting to close it: without such an assumption the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential answer to my question is Hsu's Multiple Comparisons with the Best (MCB) test.

See the original paper for more information. I'm investigating whether this is still considered the most appropriate thing to do, or potential alternatives.

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176346732

Comment: That paper looks relevant, but (based on the abstract) it appears to answer a different question: namely, constructing simultaneous confidence intervals for the group means.